# PHP move_uploaded_file equivalent in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have this code that helps me to open a file input when I click on an image:

```
HTML/PHP:
<label for="img-input">
  <img src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-1">
  <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center"><strong><?php echo basename($file[$n]); ?></strong></div>
</label>
<input type="file" id="img-input">
```

where "$file[$n]" is the address of the file on the server folder. There is a bunch of image that are rendered on the screen and when I click on one them, the file input opens. That is ok.
What I would like to do is that when I select a image from the file input by clicking on a specific image, The selected image should replace the image I clicked before.

I read many uploading solutions with JQuery but none provided the solution I wanted. Do someone know a way to handle that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't have `move_uploaded_file` in javascript, because js is client-side script. You have to upload the new file to server and **then** replace old file with php code

Comment: Is there a way to embed php code in JQuery function and get it processed by PHP instead of JS to get it done server-side instead of client-side?

Comment: I really don't know... but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use only JS for changing preview of picture in page.

[Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

If you want it to also change on server side then you should use AJAX solution. This solution are more complex, but you can find a lot of tutorials in internet.